# How can I check if dialer app is installed?

Tags: android

I mean, how can I check that user's device is not a tablet (or music player) without dialer? 
P.S.: My app uses numeric codes entered in dialer, so I want to check it's presence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be what I've needed:

```
public static String TelephonyChecker (Context context) {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE){
            return "Off";
        }else{
            return "On";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

It is a always a good approach to check if the intent receiver/activity actually exists before you attempt to invoke it.

Some of the reasons being:

If a non-existent intent, you application will force close.
If the intent receiver is not present, you might want to redirect the user to the market to download the necessary application.
Depending on the existence of an intent you might want to make menu options appear/disappear.

The following snippet contains two functions: isIntentAvailable() and isActivityAvailable() ,which can perform the checking and return a boolean accordingly.

```
public boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List resolveInfo =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   if (resolveInfo.size() > 0) {
     return true;
    }
   return false;
}
```

Just pass your action string as a parameter to this function before using it to start any third party application.